# countdown with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in a Sharepoint 2010 site with countdown to a specific date. Its rendered but its not moving, its just there. I wonder what can be wrong on this code.

```
<

script class="ms-rteForeColor-3" type="text/javascript">


$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date(2013, 7 - 1, 27);
    $('#countdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    });</script><div id="countdownBox"><h3 class="ms-rteElement-H3 ms-rteForeColor-3">Countdown to go-live</h3>
<div class="hasCountdown" id="countdown" jquery16409200090109471424="11"><span class="countdown_row countdown_show4"><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">24</span><br/>Days</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">13</span><br/>Hours</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">31</span><br/>Minutes</span><span class="countdown_section"><span class="countdown_amount">59</span><br/>Seconds</span></span></div></div>
```

Comment: why you again open `<script>` tag?

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: have you included the `countdown` plugin

Comment: I didnt develop this, i have to fix it. :( but indeed I can remove the script tag, in the console I see this: HTML1114: Codepage unicode from (UNICODE byte order mark) overrides conflicting codepage windows-1252 from (11)

Comment: @ArunPJohny no, pleae explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not included the countdown plugin [download it](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and include both css and js files.

Your markup should be as simple as

```
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Fnsgk/)